# Django 2 / Python 3.6.3 STATIC_ROOT and javascript on Windows

Tags: django, python-3.6

Python: 3.6.3  //  Django: 2.0.2

I am writting a Django app.  I am developing it using PyCharm on Windows.  I am debugging it on Windows.  I am deploying it to a linux box.

the linux side of things just works.  The Windows side seems to forget about STATIC resources.  Sometimes the app will load my project css file, sometimes not.  It almost never loads the project js file.

The Static portion of my settings file looks like:

```
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_BASE_DIR, "public/static/")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       # os.path.join(SITE_BASE_DIR, "public/static"),
    ]
```

This setup works ok on linux but windows gets confused.

On windows, if I uncomment the STATICFILES_DIRS entry (leaving STATIC_ROOT uncommented) then the css and js resources seems to work.  On linux it complains about duplicate items in STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS.

The static structure looks like

```
    |-- public
    |   |-- favicon.gif
    |   |-- favicon.ico
    |   `-- static
    |       |-- MyApp
    |       |   |-- css
    |       |   |   `-- index.css
    |       |   `-- js
    |       |       `-- index.js
    |       |-- admin
    |       |   |. . .
    |       `-- django_extensions
    |           |. . .
```

This must be my fault but I'm not seeing where I am goofing up.

Comment: are you using `collectstatic`?

Comment: yes, but as @MichaelB points out below, I am doing it in a dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue #1: `STATIC_ROOT` vs. `STATICFILES_DIRS`**

---

**[`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT)** is not supposed to be the location of where your static files ***are***. When you run the **`collectstatic`** command, it puts all of the static files into the directory specified by **[`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT)**.

The documentation has a warning on this is well:

> This should be an initially empty destination directory for collecting your static files from their permanent locations into one directory for ease of deployment; it is not a place to store your static files permanently. You should do that in directories that will be found by staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are 'static/' app sub-directories and any directories you include in **[`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)**).

If you set the **`STATIC_ROOT`** to the same path as one of the locations in the **`STATICFILES_DIRS`**, Django will complain to you, because if you actually ran  **`collectstatic`**, it would try to overwrite the files. It would basically be like telling Django to copy files from **`/public/static/`** to **`/public/static/`**, which is why it throws that error.

**Issue #2: Serving static files in a development environment**

---

In regards to Windows not finding the static files, my assumption is that you are attempting to serve the files in a development environment (e.g. `DEBUG = True`). I would suggest reading the documentation on **[Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)** section of the documentation to remedy this situation.